# How to zip folders using powershell

Tags: powershell

I run a program in windows powershell which lists name of files which have been modified before 30 days. I need to compress these files in a zip format. What should be the code?

```
#List all the folders in G:\logfiles
$folders = (Get-ChildItem -Path "G:\logfiles" | Where-Object {$_.Attributes -eq "Directory"} | Select Fullname)
#looping all folders
Foreach ($folder in $folders)
{
  $files = Get-ChildItem G:\logfiles\$folder | Where{$_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-30)
}
Foreach ($file in $files)
{
  Move-Item $file G:\logfiles\$folder\$N        # *To move files to a folder name $N*
}
```

Comment: There is a flaw in you logic. Your first for loop will overwrite `$files` every time. Was that just a typo?

Answer (score 1):

I will refer you to [powershell 5.0](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48729) and the new [Compress-Archive](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn841358.aspx) cmdlet

```
Compress-Archive -DestinationPath $folderToZip
```

Comment: Hey Alexis, I am trying to zip all files that are 30 days old but unable to find out the way. What should be added here in the script

Foreach ($folder in $folders)
{
  $files = Get-ChildItem -Path G:\logfiles\$folder | Where{$_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-30)
}
Foreach ($file in $files)
{
  Move-Item $file G:\logfiles\$folder\Name        
}

Comment: So you have a got a list of files and are moving them to a new directory.
All that seems left to do is compress the new directory using compress-archive -DestinationPath  G:\logfiles\$folder\$N

Answer (score 0):

**With the down function you can compress your files.**

```
function zipFile($Source ,$DestZip ){
$folder = Get-Item -Path $Source
$ZipFileName  = $DestZip + ".zip"

set-content $ZipFileName ("PK" + [char]5 + [char]6 + ("$([char]0)" * 18))

# Wait for the zip file to be created. 
while (!(Test-Path -PathType leaf -Path $ZipFileName))
{
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 20
}

$ZipFile = (new-object -com shell.application).NameSpace($ZipFileName)

#BACKUP - COPY
$ZipFile.CopyHere($Source)

Write-Host "#Created zip file :" $DestZip
```

}